# PreBuiltTransportClient Writes Message : ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j2

From the java client, attempting to connect to elastic search by Making use of PreBuiltTransportClient  with the below code,

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "clustername").build(); 
PreBuiltTransportClient client1 = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
```

Upon instantiation of PreBuiltTransportClient, the connection is successful but there is a message written to the console stating *"ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging."*

Is there any configuration that needs to be done at the elastic search server(elastic search log4j2.properties) or at the java client side ?

Answer (score 0):

It requires Log4j 2 configuration file in classpath. At the java client side, need to add in src/main/resources project dir, a log4j2.properties file like:

```
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %marker%m%n

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = console
```